# Show second div on hover and keep it visible with an active class on hover element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 problems with a hover function:

When I hover `.cate-name` I´m showing `dd.sub-cate` - but when I leave `.cate-name`it hides the `dd.sub-cate` element. How do I keep it visible when I hover the displayed element aswell?

The second problem is that I want to add an `active` class to the `.cate-name` element when `dd.sub-cate` is visible. I guess i need to use :visible somehow?

I also need the function to only work on the parent container - `.categories-list-box`

Script:

```
   $(".cl-item .cate-name").on({ 
     mouseenter: function () {
   $(this).closest('dl.cl-item').find("dd.sub-cate").show();
   },
     mouseleave: function () {
   $(this).closest('dl.cl-item').find("dd.sub-cate").hide();
   }
   });
```

HTML

```
<div class="categories-list-box">    
 <dl class="cl-item>
  <dt class="cate-name"><span><a href="#>Clothing</a></span></dt>
  <dd class="sub-cate" style="display: none;"></dd>
 </dl>
</div>

<div class="categories-list-box">    
 <dl class="cl-item>
  <dt class="cate-name"><span><a href="#>Shoes</a></span></dt>
  <dd class="sub-cate" style="display: none;"></dd>
 </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you just want something like this

```
$('.cl-item').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('dd.sub-cate').toggleClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yLxu6qt7/3

Comment: Yeah, that works better. I just need to an .active class to the .cl-item as well as long as the dd.sub-cate is visible

Comment: updated code in my answer, as hover is on `.cl-item` then `dd.sub-cate` will be visible till all `cl-item` is hovered

Comment: changed it to `$('.cl-item').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").find('dd.sub-cate').toggleClass("active");
});` and it works as i want, thanks"